# How to pass an Image object from QML to a C++ plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've been trying to convert an existing Qt 4.x project for decoding QR codes into to a Qt 5.0 QML plugin. So far the ported code builds, but while trying to use it I've stumbled upon an issue.

### C++ side

I'm having problems passing an Image component to the plugin. Essentially, [this cast always fails returning 0](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/+junk/qzxing-plugin/view/head:/imagehandler.cpp#L17):

```
QGraphicsObject *item = qobject_cast<QGraphicsObject*>(imageObj);
```

### QML side

For reference, on the QML side I'm essentially passing an Image (`qrcode`) to the C++ plugin:

```
decoder.decodeImageQML(qrcode);
```

Where `decoder` is:

```
QZXing {
    id: decoder
    onTagFound: console.log("Tag found: " + tag)
    onDecodingStarted: console.log("Decoding started")
    onDecodingFinished: console.log("Decoding finished " + (succeeded==true ? "successfully" : "unsuccessfully"))
}
```

My Qt/C++ knowledge is rather limited, so I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious and an expert can give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong.

- [My Qt 5.0 QML plugin port](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/+junk/qzxing-plugin/files)
- [Original Qt 4.x project](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/QZXing)

Comment: Are you using `QtQucik 2.0` in your QML project?

Comment: Yes, it's a Qt 5 project that uses QtQuick 2

Comment: So. It should be QQuickItem instead of QGraphicItem. You might find it hard to get image from as it's content is only available as OpenGL texture.

Comment: You need to read source property and load Image yourself. Also http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html only provide file location.